# Customizing moodle sign up form

Tags: php, moodle

I need to add attachment input to moodle sign up form
This file input is not supported by moodle through the standard [user profile fields](https://docs.moodle.org/31/en/User_profile_fields).

So I tried to add it manually:
I added:

```
$mform->addElement('file', 'attach', "Attach", null,array( 'accepted_types' => 'pdf'));
$mform->setType('attach', PARAM_RAW);
$mform->addRule('attach', 'Missing File Attachment', 'required', null, 'client');
```

But where should I tell Moodle to insert that value into the database?

Answer (score 0):

You should probably first add a custom user profile field, as described [here](https://docs.moodle.org/dev/User_profile_fields). Here you should override the function `profile_save_data($usernew)` to tell the system where you want to save your file. 
If you want to learn how to get the file from the form and save it  you can go [here](https://docs.moodle.org/dev/Using_the_File_API_in_Moodle_forms). In particular, you could use the `filepicker` form element, which replaces the old `file` element, with

```
$mform->addElement('filepicker', 'userfile', get_string('file'), null,
                   array('maxbytes' => $maxbytes, 'accepted_types' => 'pdf'));
```

Get the file content and file name as well as store it with:

```
$content = $mform->get_file_content('userfile');
$name = $mform->get_new_filename('userfile');
$success = $mform->save_file('userfile', $fullpath, $override);
```

where `$fullpath` is a path in the file sytem  (such as the `moodledata` folder) and `$override` is a boolean meaning "override file if exists".
DISCLAIMER: I did not try this solution myself.